# SQL Server cannot create indexed view

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005 SP3 Standard Edition but cannot create an indexed view (trying to create a clustered index on `MeasurementDataID`). I know standard edition does not use  indexed views in a query unless noexpand query hint is used.

> Error message --  because view reference an unknown value sum aggregate of nullable expression

Also, why do I need count_big(*)  ??

```
CREATE VIEW [CPSync].[vwGetColorChars] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT MC.MeasurementDataID
       , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 11 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END ) AS [Gray_a*] 
       , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 12 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END) AS [Gray_b*]
       , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 4 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END) AS [ΔF]
       , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 9 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END) As DotGain
       , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 10 THEN     [ColorCharsValue] END) As [Gray_L*]
       , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 13 THEN     [ColorCharsValue] END) As [G7NPDC]  
       , COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountBig 
FROM CPSync.Measurement 
INNER JOIN CPSync.MeasurementData ON  Measurement.MeasurementID = MeasurementData.MeasurementID
INNER JOIN CPSync.MeasuredColorChar As MC ON MC.MeasurementDataID = MeasurementData.MeasurementDataID
INNER JOIN CPSync.ColorChar AS CC ON MC.ColorCharsID =CC.ColorCharID
Group By MC.MeasurementDataID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the lines like

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 11 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END ) AS [Gray_a*]
```

to

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 11 THEN [ColorCharsValue] ELSE 0 END ) AS [Gray_a*]
```

COUNT_BIG: if allows the materialised rows to be tracked. Like the "uniquifier" in a non-unqiue clustered index. COUNT_BIG allows for 32 bit overflow for large views.

Comment: I tried but got same error I changed all case statements like
 , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 11 THEN [ColorCharsValue] ELSE 0 END ) AS [Gray_a*]

Comment: exact error message after changing all case statements ELSE 0 Cannot create the clustered index "IX_MeasuremnetDataID" on view "vwGetColorChars" because the view references an unknown value (SUM aggregate of nullable expression). Consider referencing only non-nullable values in SUM. ISNULL() may be useful for this. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 8662) For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4053&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=8662&LinkId=20476 ------------------------------ BUTTONS: OK ------------------------------

Comment: Use isnull(ColorCharsValue,0) then?

Comment: @cshah: please don't post **large** error messages and stuff here in comments - it's a real pain to read and decipher. Please **update** your original question with additional information by editing it! Thanks.

Comment: Arvo, it worked after I changed isnull(colorcharvalue, 0) Thanks,

Comment: mark_c, Noted, I really need to read how to post question in this forum, little flunky as enter key actually post your comment instead clicking on a button

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can replace this:

```
SELECT MC.MeasurementDataID
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 11 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END ) AS [Gray_a*] 
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 12 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END) AS [Gray_b*]
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 4 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END) AS [ΔF]
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 9 THEN [ColorCharsValue] END) As DotGain
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 10 THEN     [ColorCharsValue] END) As [Gray_L*]
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CC.ColorCharID = 13 THEN     [ColorCharsValue] END) As [G7NPDC]  
   , COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountBig
```

with this simpler code:

```
SELECT MC.MeasurementDataID,
   , CC.ColorCharID
   , SUM([ColorCharsValue] ) AS [yourColumnName] 
   , COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountBig
```

and pivot it when you select from your indexed view

Comment: What do you mean by 'PIVOT IT' when you select from your indexed view? Can you show us what that'd look like?